# Enums in Ruby and getting string value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, module

I have the following module in one of my rails models:

```
module Color
   RED = 0
   BLUE = 1
   YELLOW = 2
end
```

I store these values in a db as ints by doing `Color::RED` etc.  When I retrieve the values back I want to get the string, ie "red".  But I am having trouble converting 0 -> "RED"/"red".  What am I missing?  Can I do this with the module approach or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [rails enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)?

Comment: I'm not using ActiveRecord so I get 
`NoMethodError: undefined method `enum' for Event:Class` and also using Rails 3.2

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you expect your database to return `"red"` instead of `0`?

Comment: The conversion must be done within your model. Your database is not aware of your `Color` module or its constants.

Comment: Even though this code *looks* like an enum from C-family languages, it's not. It's just a module with three constants defined. To accomplish what you want, you should use a different data structure, such as a hash as described by @Nimir below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you cannot use Rails ActiveRecord `enum`, then a hash might be useful:

```
COLORS = { "red" => 0, "blue" => 1, "yellow" => 2 }
```

#### store a color code

```
red_color = COLORS["red"] #red_color = 0
```

#### convert from color code, use [Hash#key](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key) method

```
COLORS.key(0)
# > "red"
```

You can even make a helper for that, something like:

```
def color_code_to_string(code)
  COLORS.key(code) # returning a default color in case if wrong code number is a good idea too
end
```

Comment: Unless OP has a particular need for symbol keys, I think it makes more sense to use string keys here (`COLORS = { "red" => 0, ... }`) so `to_s` isn't necessary on the last line.

Comment: @Jordan: Isn't a hash lookup faster using symbols than using strings?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, about 50% faster ([I benchmarked it](https://gist.github.com/jrunning/1eddc4133bdfd52e382b6aea7d257c4e)). However, if OP is doing more lookups by value than by key, and calling `to_s` every time, that advantage might easily be negated. Either way it's a premature optimization, in my opinion. If performance is an issue, then `COLORs.key(code)` is the bigger problem, since `Hash#key` is O(n) (versus O(1) for `Hash#[]`).